# Headless cms access wp-admin(nuxt.js + wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, vue.js, nuxt.js, wordpress-rest-api

I have a problem. I installed the wordpress and enabled rest api. After that I built nuxt.js app.

It starts at localhost:3000 (when I run npm run dev")

I positioned xampp so that document root of server is at wordpress folder.

When i try localhost/wp-admin I get the acess to admin panel but if I try localhost:3000/wp-admin I cannot access it.

Anyone has idea how to access it

Comment: xampp listening on port 80 and dev server listening on port 3000 and they have not any relation together

Comment: I tried pointing to 3000 but not I can't even acess the nuxt.js app

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **npm run build**, In that way you can run your application to the root domain.

Thanks